# Product of two consecutive Fibonacci numbers - code times out

Tags: java, timeout, fibonacci

I am trying to solve Product of consecutive Fib numbers on Codewars in Java. 
Sample tests run fine, but when i click Attempt, it times out.

What might be my mistake?

You can find the task details here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/product-of-consecutive-fib-numbers

```
public class ProdFib { 
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {

int a = 0;
int ta, ta2= 0;
int a2 = 1;

while (a * a2 <= prod){
    ta = a;
    ta2 = a2;
    a2 = a + a2;
    a = ta2;

    if(a * a2 == prod){
    long[] re = new long[]{a,a2,1};
    return re;
    }
    if(a * a2 > prod){
    long[] re = new long[]{a,a2,0};
    return re;
    }
}
return null;
   }
 }
```

Comment: "Sample tests run fine" - please show it in your code.  "when i click Attempt" - no idea what this means

Comment: Do you know the test-inputs codewars uses?

Comment: It runs my code against the full test suite, so basically 2 tests run successfully, the others time out

Comment: @DávidKatona what happens when you use this: https://ideone.com/RQVeCR, it's a minified version made by me from your approach

Comment: public void test1() {
  long[] r = new long[] {55, 89, 1};
  assertArrayEquals(r, ProdFib.productFib(4895));

Comment: @Lino  Tried it. same results. Sample tests run fine, full tests time out. But Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you define your variables as `int` instead of `long`.

If you try running your program with the prod `44361286907595736L` it's going to go into an endless loop. The reason for this is that when you multiply two `int`s, the result is also an `int`. That prod is the result of multyplying 165580141 and 267914296. These are legitimate ints, but when you multiply them, the number is too big for an int - integer overflow. So you get a number that is much lower than `44361286907595736L`. and your loop doesn't stop.

If you define your variables as `long`, this won't happen. Here is a slightly more readable version of your program.

```
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {

    long prev = 0;
    long curr = 1;
    long multiplied = prev * curr;

    while (multiplied < prod) {
        long temp = curr;
        curr += prev;
        prev = temp;
        multiplied = prev * curr;
    }

    return new long[] { prev, curr, multiplied == prod ? 1 : 0 };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem definition:
Input: product - the wanted product
Output: array of 3 elements: 
        {F1, F2, result}

Where F1 is the first Fibonacci number,
      F2 is the second Fibonacci number,
      result equals 1 if F1 * F2 = product,
      otherwise: result = 0

This problem can be solved more efficiently by using the following formulas:
1. Direct formula for getting the n'th Fibonacci number.
2. Direct formula for getting the index of a given Fibonacci number.

You can get the relevant formulas & explanations in the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

The idea is to get the index of the Fibonacci number: sqrt(product)

Then we can get to the next and previous Fibonacci numbers and compare their products against the given product

This is the relevant Java code:

```
private static double phi = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;

public static void main(String[] args) { 
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(800))); // [34, 55, 0]
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(714))); // [21, 34, 1]
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(15))); // [3, 5, 1]
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(40))); // [5, 8, 1]
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(2))); // [1, 2, 1]
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fibProd(3))); // [2, 3, 0]
}

private static long[] fibProd(long product) {
    long currentIndex = getFibIndex(Math.round(Math.sqrt(product)));
    long currentElement = getFibElement(currentIndex);
    long previousElement = getFibElement(currentIndex - 1);
    long nextElement = getFibElement(currentIndex + 1);

    int c1 = Long.compare(previousElement * currentElement, product);

    if(c1 == 0) {
        return new long[] {previousElement, currentElement, 1};
    }

    int c2 = Long.compare(currentElement * nextElement, product);

    if(c2 == 0) {
        return new long[] {currentElement, nextElement, 1};
    }

    if (c1 < c2) {
        return new long[] {currentElement, nextElement, 0};
    } else {
        return new long[] {previousElement, currentElement, 0};
    }
}

private static long getFibIndex(long item) 
{ 
    double m = item * Math.sqrt(5) + 0.5;
    return Math.round(Math.log(m) / Math.log(phi));
}

private static long getFibElement(long index) {
    return Math.round(Math.pow(phi, index)  / Math.sqrt(5)); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public class ProdFib {
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {
    int i = 0;
    int f1 = 0;
    int f2 = 0;
    while ((f(i) * f(i + 1) != prod && f(i) * f(i + 1) < prod)) {
        i += 1;
        f1 = f(i);
        f2 = f(i + 1);
    }
    if (f1 * f2 == prod)
        return new long[] { f1, f2, 1 };
    else
        return new long[] { f1, f2, 0 };
}

public static int f(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return f(i - 2) + f(i - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] r = productFib(1000);
    System.out.println(r[0] + " " + r[1] + " " + r[2]);
}
```

}

Comment: You are running a recursive function six times in each iteration. The efficiency of this algorithm is *horrible*, esepcially as the numbers remain the same for each iteration.

Comment: @Lino yes, I wasn't even counting the calls inside the function itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Oh I missed those in the while-body, so its probably at minimum 12 calls... not quite the most performant way